# How to add text to an existing .txt file in Java?

Tags: java

I would like to add more text to an existing text file in ***Java*?**
When i try to add more text it just replaces the existing text.

Comment: What is the code you are using now? When opening a FileOutputStream, there is an "append" option.

Comment: im using java                     .

Answer (score 0):

This will append `mycontent` to the `outputFile`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String content = "mycontent";
            File outputFile = new File("PATH/test.txt");
            Files.write(outputFile.toPath(), content.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Available since Java 1.7.

Comment: what do i have to import

Comment: modified to a complete example

Comment: what do you use to run this

Comment: I use jdk1.8.0_77, and I run it from Eclipse. What Java version are you on?